# Reading bin files in python - what to learn

Tags: python, c, parsing, ctypes

I have a .bin file created by scientific device, as well as a .h file, describing the data structure (more than 1000 lines).

I want to read this file into python for further analysis. I am somewhat experienced in python, however completely overwhelmed by this problem. I don't really have an exact question, but I want to know, what is the pathway to do this, and what do I have to learn? At this point I'm not even sure what to google.

If I don't find a better idea, I will have to learn c, write a c code that loads the .bin file, and then stores the data in a .csv file, which I can then read in python.

What I have tried so far (thanks to chatgpt): I created a module with ctypesgen using my .h file, and imported it to my python file. Now I'm not sure how to continue. This is the basic structure of the data. Generally speaking it should contain 3000 packs of data, which each contain measurement data as well as other data.

```
PACK(struct xStatusType
{
  struct priv_timeval           TimeOfDayMaster;
  struct IWG1Type               IWG1Data;
  uint8_t                       bPumpDataValid;
  struct xPumpStatusType        xPumpStatus;
  uint8_t                       bDetDataValid; 
  struct xDetStatusType         xDetStatus;
  struct NTPStatType            NTPStatus;             
  uint16_t                      InstrumentAction;       
});
```

Comment: Take a look at the `struct` module. It allows you to define format strings for processing structured binary data.

Comment: Also see [`cstruct`](https://pypi.org/project/cstruct/1.0/)

Comment: unpack_from into a list indexing the offset by the size as you go to work through the file.

Answer (score 1):

A complete structure definition wasn't given, but this should give you an idea how to read and write fixed-structure data with `ctypes`:

```py
import ctypes as ct

# A simple structure
class A(ct.Structure):
    _pack_ = 1  # to prevent padding bytes for misaligned data
    _fields_ = (('a', ct.c_int32),  # size 4
                ('b', ct.c_uint8),  # size 1
                ('c', ct.c_uint16)) # size 2 (total 7)
    def __repr__(self):
        return f'A(a={self.a}, b={self.b}, c={self.c})'

# A structure with nested structure
class B(ct.Structure):
    _pack_ = 1
    _fields_ = (('a', A),           # size 7
                ('b', ct.c_uint8))  # size 1 (total 8)
    def __repr__(self):
        return f'B(a={self.a}, b={self.b})'

with open('out.bin', 'wb') as fout:
    # write a couple of records
    a = A(1,2,3)
    b = B(a, 4)
    to_write = bytes(b)
    print(to_write)
    fout.write(to_write)
    a = A(5,6,7)
    b = B(a, 8)
    to_write = bytes(b)
    print(to_write)
    fout.write(to_write)

print()
with open('out.bin', 'rb') as fin:
    while data := fin.read(ct.sizeof(B)):  # while breaks if no data read
        print(data)
        b = B.from_buffer_copy(data)  # copy byte data into structure
        print(b)
```

Output:

```
b'\x01\x00\x00\x00\x02\x03\x00\x04'
b'\x05\x00\x00\x00\x06\x07\x00\x08'

b'\x01\x00\x00\x00\x02\x03\x00\x04'
B(a=A(a=1, b=2, c=3), b=4)
b'\x05\x00\x00\x00\x06\x07\x00\x08'
B(a=A(a=5, b=6, c=7), b=8)
```